# Iterate through two collections concurrently

Tags: arrays, go, channel

In Go, what is the best way to iterate through 2 collections concurrently?

In my program, I have one function that creates two arrays, and another function that need to iterate over them simultaneously (in each iteration access the I'th element in both of the arrays).

If I had a single input, I would have created a channel in the first function (instead of an array), and used range loops to iterate over it from various goroutines.

In this case, is there a simpler solution than creating a channel of indexes and using it to access the arrays?

```
func main() {
    // Prepare two arrays.
    arrA := [12]int{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144}
    arrB := arrA

    // Create a channel with the indexes.
    c := make(chan int, len(arrA))
    for i := range arrA {
        c <- i
    }
    close(c)

    poolSize := 3
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(poolSize)

    for i := 1; i <= poolSize; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for j := range c {
                fmt.Printf("%v == %v\n", arrA[j], arrB[j])
            }
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a saying in go

> "Don't communicate by sharing memory, share memory by communicating"

It basically boils down to;

"Don't share state across 2 goroutines, instead pass the values needed between the routines, using channels"

It may be a biproduct of your simplified example, but instead of passing the indicies, why can't you limit the scope of the `arrA` and `arrB` to be inside a single goroutine, some kind of producer or generator that will send the values. The receiver of those values can do the work on them, in this case equal comparisons.

```
type pair struct {
    a, b int
}

c := make(chan pair, len(arrA))
for i := range arrA {
    c <- pair{a: arrA[i], b: arrB[i]}
}
close(c)

poolSize := 3
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(poolSize)

for _ := range poolSize {
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for p := range c {
            fmt.Printf("%v == %v\n", p.a, p.b)
        }
    }
}
```

This might seem like a trivially small change but the benefits are:

1. **Isolation**: you are limiting the scope of accessors to arrA and arrB to a single producing goroutine, limit the scope for race conditions / complex logic / bugs later on in the code.
2. **Reuse**: you can reuse the code functions that consume a `chan pair` elsewhere in the codebase as they do not directly access the values in specific arrays, instead are passed all the values they need.

To extend this; assuming that you only need the value from `arrB` and do not care about the index, then you should send that value on the channel, and remove the need for the `pair` type.